# Why am I getting different outputs from my reducer function after splitting a string and concatenating it back together?

Tags: java, hadoop, split, reducers

I understand that is kind of a strange question. Let me provide examples. I am writing a reducer function that essentially concatenates the values from the `Iterator` that it receives. The strings in the iterator are in the form "%s,%s,%s". When I write my code like this:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder indexValue = new StringBuilder();
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            String data = values.next().toString();
            indexValue.append(data);
        }

        output.collect(key, new Text(indexValue.toString()));
}
```

I get output that seems correct. It is in the form "%s,%s,%s%s,%s,%s..."

However, when I write my code like this:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder indexValue = new StringBuilder();
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            String data = values.next().toString();
            String [] parts = data.split(",");
            indexValue.append(parts[0] + "," + parts[1] + "," + parts[2]);
        }

        output.collect(key, new Text(indexValue.toString()));
}
```

I get a completely different, weird output. First of all, the output does *not* contain all of the values that should have been concatenated. Secondly, it is in a form that makes no sense to me. It looks something like "%s,%s,%s%s". Clearly there is some missing information there.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I'm completely stumped.

EDIT: I was asked for the original data, here it is. I'll also provide the mapper function below.

Mapper function:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String [] parts = line.split("\t");

        int frequency = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        String [] documentDataParts = parts[0].split(",");

        String term = documentDataParts[0];
        String bookFilename = documentDataParts[1];
        String chunk = documentDataParts[2];

        String documentData = bookFilename + "," + chunk + "," + frequency;
        output.collect(new Text(term), new Text(documentData));
}
```

Data Sample:

```
Ages,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,5545 1
Aggeus,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,1268 1
Aggravateth,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,995     1
Aggravateth,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,999     1
Aggravation,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,1015    1
Aggravation,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,1691    1
Aggregate,LeviathanbyThomasHobbes.txt,1293      1
Agier,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,2790        1
Agincourt,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,1510    1
Agn,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,5114  1
Agnes,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,6450        1
Agnese,LesMiserablesbyVictorHugo.txt,580        1
Agnus,UlyssesbyJamesJoyce.txt,1827      1
```

Comment: You question is confusing to me. Also, if you are using a string builder why are you concatenating strings? Kinda defeats the purpose of StringBuilder.

Comment: I agree that concatenating the strings defeats the purpose of using the StringBuilder, but that still shouldn't affect the output. My question boils down to - why are these two code segments giving me completely different outputs?

Comment: I would have to see original data.

Comment: I made an edit to show the mapper function and a sample of the original data.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I disagree that concatenating defeats the purpose of `StringBuilder`. Concatenating is a pretty cheap operation on a small scale. The main benefit of the builder is when the string grows in length as the loop progresses.

Comment: @Solomon Are you sure the iterator is only returning one line at a time?

Comment: I'm fairly sure. That's how the Hadoop map and reduce functions work. Plus, if I System.out.println() each value, then they look correct.

Comment: I not sure what is going on, but I would start by putting System.out.println(data); after String data = values.next().toString();

Comment: It looks like (I don't see any other possibilities) that some of your lines in input file contain empty strings, like Ages,,, 1

Comment: I have good reason to believe that there are no empty strings in the input file because the input file comes from another map reduce job that I wrote, and I do not write any strings to file if they're empty.

Comment: So I am printing the length of parts each time, and they are all completely different. Some are length 3, some length 10, some length 0, some length 20,000. I printed all of the values in parts and it looks like somehow the result from indexValue is being assigned to data